# Big o of for loop with multiplication iteration

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

For(int i=1;i<=n;i*=2)
    Statement
I'm making notes for competitive exam and made this problem. But I'm not getting solution. Is it O( log n)? If so why?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: See also questions tagged [tag:algorithm-analysis+loops].

Comment: Try what happens if n = 1,000,000. That should help understanding and answering the "why".